Method Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel::setAccessCondition does not exist
I am trying to hide edit and update button from trashed items but getting error 'Method Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel::setAccessCondition does not exist.'
backpack: 5.x
Laravel: 8.x
public function setupTrashOperation()
{
    CRUD::setOperationSetting('withTrashFilter', false);
    CRUD::setAccessCondition(['update', 'show'], function($entry) {
        return ! $entry->trashed();
    });
}


Thats method is from Backpack v6.
Cheers.
